# How to ignore a variable in JSON data in Angular TypeScript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular7

I am facing a problem while reading a JSON file in angular 7.

below is the format of my JSON data file.

```
[
   {
      "attributes":  {
        "User": "jay"
    }
},
   {
      "attributes": {
        "User": "roy"
    }
},
    {
      "attributes":{
        "User": "kiya"
    }
},
    {
      "attributes":{
        "User": "gini"
    }
},
   {
      "attributes": {
        "User": "rock"
    }
},
   {
      "attributes": {
        "User": "joy"
    }
}

]
```

here is my component.ts file method in which I am calling service for a JSON file.

```
        this.rest.getUsers().subscribe((data: {}) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.items = data;
            //this.items=data;
        });
```

Here is my service.ts file method.

```
 private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res;
  return body || { };
}

getUsers():Observable<any> {
    return this.httpService.get('./assets/usersdetails.json').pipe(
    map(this.extractData));
}
```

Now I want to read only `User` from the JSON file and I want to filter the word `attributes`. is there any way to filter this thing from JSON file, so that I can only get the `User value`. because in my Project this `attributes` in JSON is creating a problem and I want to ignore or filter this.

because in my application I need to read the JSON as below format.

```
[
    {
        "User": "jay"
    },
    {
        "User": "roy"
    },
    {
        "User": "kiya"
    },
    {
        "User": "gini"
    },
    {
        "User": "rock"
    },
    {
        "User": "joy"
    }

]
```

but the data is coming in the format as above mentioned JSON format with `attributes`

so is there any way to filter the extra `attributes` thing from the JSON at the time of reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show the code for the `extractData` method, so it is hard to say what isn't working there, but you should be able to accomplish your goals with the following.

```
return this.httpService
           .get('./assets/usersdetails.json')
           .pipe(
             map(data => data.map(d => d.attributes))
           );
```

If there are other properties on 'attributes' and you really only want the 'user' data, then you could further update the code to:

```
return this.httpService
           .get('./assets/usersdetails.json')
           .pipe(
             map(data => data.map(d => ({ 'User': d.attributes.User })))
           );
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, but it is giving error as - error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.